# Macbook air 2014 13" wireless driver

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom, macbook-air

just installed ubuntu on a macbook air, but cant seem to find bcmwl that actually finishes the installation.
I can't connect via ethernet so that's not an option.

can someone give me a source or steps how to fix this ?

some details: BCM4360 802.11ac [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on mine. 
Mac air 6.2 (mid2013) Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

**Specs**: (lspci -vnn | grep -i net)

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
```

The broadcom drivers don't work for that wireless adaptor.

I solved the problem by installing the wl driver. And disabling some other modules

1. **Get the driver package** (with ethernet)

   ```
   vim /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```

   add this lines:

   ```
   # Debian 7 "Wheezy"
   deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
   ```

   and **save the file**

   **or** simply execute:

   ```
   apt-add-repository -y "deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free"
   ```

   **then**, get the new packages:

   ```
   apt-get update
   apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms
   ```

   **Or without ethernet**

   You will have to [compile it from Source](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/broadcom-sta-dkms).
2. **Unload conflicting drivers**

   ```
   modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac
   ```
3. **Load `wl` module**

   ```
   modprobe wl
   ```

Worked for me after hours of looking for the answer.

Based on this answer:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175810/how-to-install-broadcom-bcm4360-on-debian-on-macbook-pro